# How do focus and blur bubble up the DOM when switching between children?

Tags: javascript, events

When switching focus between children of a `<div>`, I'd like to fire a function. (The children are `<span>`s, if that matters). I know I can handle this by binding the function to the `blur` event of each of the children, but I'll potentially be creating (and destroying) lots of child elements, and would like to avoid binding the function to the children themselves.

For many events, like click or mouseover, I know that the event will bubble up the DOM and fire the same event on my parent div, where I can catch it and handle it. I'm not sure how blur and focus events would bubble, though. It seems like the parent still has focus, since one of its children has focus, but javascript is a strange and beautiful creature.

Can I rely on blur/focus events bubbling up when changing between children of an element, or is there a better way of handling changing focus between the children?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bubbling should work fine with blur and focus

```
var myElem = document.getElementById("foo");
myElem.addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
    console.log("blur: " + elem.name);
}, true);
myElem.addEventListener('focus', function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
    console.log("focus: " + elem.name);
}, true);
```

IE uses onfocusin and onfocusout instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/p6bAL/

Comment: No, the events don't bubble. The reason this is working is the third parameter for addEventListener, which enables event capturing (basically bubbling downward the DOM).

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts is right. Use `focusin` or `focusout` event instead. these events bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

`focus` and `blur` do not have a bubbling phase - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event

Instead, you can use `focusin` that has bubbling.